# Are the following rings Artinian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, artinian

I am trying to figure out whether the following ring is artinian:

$R = \left\{\left( \begin{array}{cc}
a & b  \\
0 & a  \\
\end{array} \right)\mid a,b \in \mathbb{C}\right\}$.

I understand that if $\mathbb{C}$ were instead replaced by a finite field then $R$ would be artinian as it is finite. However, I am struggling to see whether this is still the case when finite is replaced by infinite.

Comment: The accepted answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1567500/110831) is also an answer to yours.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: a left (right) ideal is a vector subspace.