# $G$ is an finite group and nonabelian so to the regular module $\mathbb{C}[G]$, there is infinity number of submodule

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules, representation-theory

I trying to understand why if $G$ is an finite group and nonabelian so to the regular module $\mathbb{C}[G]$ (were $\mathbb{C}$ is the complex field), there is infinity number of submodule, so it mean that there is more than one why to write the direct sum of sub representations.
I know that if $G$ nonabelian so there is at least one component that its not one-dimensional, but how can I finish it and realize for this that there is infinity number of submodule ?

Note: I saw an Similar question but the answer was about ideal and I didn't learn it so I didn't understand the answer, so if there is an anther answer with no ideals I'll be thankful.

Comment: You should use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to make your maths look pretty (basically, put `$...$` around all your maths-stuff, like subgroups, and use `\cap` for intersection, `\subseteq` for subset, and `\mathbb{C}` for $\mathbb{C}$). I've edited it in so you can see what the code should look like.

Comment: You do understand that a submodule of the right regular module is a right ideal, right?   Nobody can “answer with no ideal”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Maschke's theorem your ring is semisimple, and since it is noncommutative, it must contain a matrix ring $M_n(\mathbb C)$ with $n>1$.

It's established in other posts, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1567752/29335) that these rings have infinitely many maximal right ideals, for example.  The underlying field just needs to be infinite for this to work.

These right ideals are right ideals of the original group ring, of course.

Comment: But the poster asked for a solution with no ideals.

Comment: @DerekHolt A submodule of the ring is a right ideal, so I don’t see how that is possible to satisfy.

Comment: How is one going to answer “show there are infinitely many submodules of the right regular module” without talking about right ideals? They are the same thing.  As for two-sided ideals, I made no mention...

Comment: thank for the answer ! @rschwieb